# Python, item in each row to a variable

Tags: python, variables, row

Hello I have two text files which has 3 row item in each file. How can assign each of them to a variable? i would like something similar to shell script share below.

test1.txt

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

test2.txt

```
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

test.sh

```
paste test1.txt test2.txt |
while read a b c d e f etc
do echo $a $b $c $d $e $f
done
```

test.sh outputs

```
1 1 1 3 3 3
2 2 2 4 4 4
```

Comment: You are not assigning any of them to a variable... what are your expected variables supposed to carry? `'1 1 1', '3 3 3', '2 2 2', '4 4 4'`? Or `'1', '1', ...`? Or `'1 1 1 3 3 3', '2 2 2 4 4 4'`? It's unclear what you are looking for.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Idlehands and Hemanta, thank you for your support.. $a $b are a variables. each row element is a variable. i'm echoing all of them together that's why it maybe confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach

```
for line in open('myfile.txt').readlines():
    a, b, c = line.split()
    print(a, b, c)
```

input two files:

```
with open('1.txt') as f1, open('2.txt') as f2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        a, b, c = line1.split()
        d, e, f = line2.split()
        print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```